# alter diststyle in an existing table in redshift. is it possible?

Tags: amazon-redshift

instead of dropping a table and recreating it as `diststyle` all I would wish to alter the table's `diststyle`, is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Nowadays you can use `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER DISTSTYLE KEY DISTKEY column_name`, it should be followed up by `VACUUM SORT ONLY table_name`

[see docs for more details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html#r_ALTER_TABLE-synopsis). the table will be redistributed on the clusters:

> When specifying DISTSTYLE KEY, the data is distributed by the values in the DISTKEY column. For more information about DISTSTYLE, see ...

Comment: Only ALL and KEY styles are support by ALTER though, not EVEN or AUTO.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way I've found is to use the following:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE mytable_tmp
DISTSTYLE ALL -- You can also use DISTKEY(some_column) or DISTSTYLE EVEN
AS SELECT * FROM mytable;

DROP TABLE mytable;
ALTER TABLE mytable_tmp RENAME TO mytable;

COMMIT;
```

This allows you to easily modify the distkey or diststyle of a table without even knowing what columns are in that table. You only need to know the table's name.

Comment: From docs "CREATE TABLE AS (CTAS) tables don't inherit compression encodings, constraints, identity columns, default column values, or the primary key from the table that they were created from."

Above query won't copy old table's compression techniques. 
Check out http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CTAS_usage_notes.html

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't appear to be possible. Easier to recreate the table populating from the old one.

Comment: Thanks, thought i was missing something. It would have been easier to run `alter table XXX alter diststyle to all;`, but that's my opinion.

Comment: This is nice if you don't have any other attributes for a table or compression. all me fields are compressed so it's no go.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct